# Finding a specific cell contanining value greater than the desired value

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm looking for a way to return a specific cell value from a range based on an initial desired value. It looks like this:

```
DesiredValue typed in cell: | 125|
```

Search Range:

```
line1         RangeA|RangeB
line2         1     | 50
line3         51    | 100
line4         101   | 500
line5         501   | 1500
```

I'm trying to get two formulas:

the first one returns the immediate bigger value in rangeA (500 in this case), the second one returns the immediate lower value (101 in this case).

Currently I'm using a very ugly if formula, for the greater value as an example:

`if[DesiredValue]<=[b2], [B2], if [DesiredValue]<=[b3], [b3], if...`

A modified version of this formula is used to get the lower number, but it is really not the way to do it since i'm gonna have to use it in a couple hundread ranges.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *125* typed into D2 the first will return *101* from *Range A*; the second will return *500* from *Range B*.

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(D2, A:A))
=INDEX(B:B, MATCH(D2, A:A))
```

This method is known as a [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair.

[image]

When seeking approximate matches, the values to be examined *must* be in ascending order as yours are.